# Javascript) I used addEventListener to use 'mouseover' but it doesn't work. I can't figure out the problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want make my 'id=submenu' "visibility:hidden" to "visibility:visible" When I mouseover 'class=recipe'. I tried inline,property Listener but It doesn't works. I know I'm very ignorant but I can't find What should I do. Can you help me to solve this problem? Here's my code. Sorry.

```js
var t = document.getElementByClass('recipe');
t.addEventListener('mouseover', Function(sHover) {
  var a = document.getElementById('submenu');
  a.style.visibility = 'visible';
});
```

```css
#submenu {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainmenu">
  <a class="first" href="Home.html">Home</a>
  <a class="recipe" href="Recipe.html">Recipe</a>
  <a href="QNA.html">QNA</a>
  <div id="submenu">
    coffee
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error: `Function` should be `function`.

Comment: Didn't you see the error message when you tried to run your code?

Comment: I was so confused that I even forgot to check my error. Sorry for this. Thank you for your comment. I checked it and it solved. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you have to pull out the element from the array.

Also, it's not getElement.. but getElementsByClass

```
var t = document.getElementsByClass('recipe')[0];
t.addEventListener('mouseover', function(sHover) {
  var a = document.getElementById('submenu');
  a.style.visibility = 'visible';
});
```

You should consider using `querySelector(".recipe")` instead

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it Right NOW.

Comment: `getElementByClass` is not a function, try `getElementsByClassName` instead.

See this working example: https://jsfiddle.net/32rvq6zu/

Comment: Oh God.. It works. I was so ignorant. Thank you for your hard work. :)